# Angular routing not working on anchors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, angular-routing

I have just started working with Angular. Routing is not working with anchor tag. My code is

```
    (function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module("PHC",["ngRoute"])
           .controller("AuthController", AuthController).
         config(function($routeProvider) {
           $routeProvider
          .when("/", {
              templateUrl : "templates/email.html",
              controller : "AuthController"
          })
          .when("/password", {
              templateUrl : "templates/password.html",
              controller : "AuthController"
          })
          .when("/confirm-password", {
              templateUrl : "templates/confirm-password.html",
              controller : "AuthController"
          })
          .when("/name", {
              templateUrl : "templates/name.html",
              controller : "AuthController"
          });
});

    function AuthController(){
        var auth=this;
    console.log("Hello");

    }   
})();
```

If I access my pages via browser URLs directly, it works fine but when I render them using 'href' of anchor tag, it does not work

```
<button class="next-step-button mt20"><a href="#password">Next</a></button>
<button class="next-step-button mt20"><a href="#email">Go to email</a></button>
```

**Edit:**
when I click on anchors,it makes URLs like: 
http://localhost:3000/module2-solution/index.html#!/#%2Fpassword

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: What exactly happening to your route?

Comment: @sai, Please see the edit section

Comment: You can enable `html5Mode(true)` to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try to do this in your routing definition:

```
 (function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module("PHC",["ngRoute"])
           .controller("AuthController", AuthController).
         config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {


    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });

    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');


           $routeProvider
          .when("/", {
              templateUrl : "templates/email.html",
              controller : "AuthController"
          })
          .when("/password", {
              templateUrl : "templates/password.html",
              controller : "AuthController"
          })
          .when("/confirm-password", {
              templateUrl : "templates/confirm-password.html",
              controller : "AuthController"
          })
          .when("/name", {
              templateUrl : "templates/name.html",
              controller : "AuthController"
          });
});

    function AuthController(){
        var auth=this;
    console.log("Hello");

    }   
})();
```

and in your links ..

```
<button class="next-step-button mt20"><a  data-ng-href="#!password">Next</a></button>
<button class="next-step-button mt20"><a  data-ng-href="#!email">Go to email</a></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this works, change in `href` value

```
<button class="next-step-button mt20"><a  href="#!password">Next</a></button>
<button class="next-step-button mt20"><a  href="#!email">Go to email</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a / in your hrefs

Comment: I have also tried using <a href="#/password">Next</a> bit it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need add  href like

```js
href= "#/password"
```

Comment: @ahmad If it helps please accept the answer for making it clear to others :)

Comment: I have also tried <a href="#/password">Next</a> it is not working

Comment: what url it redirecting  ?